# Not sure "will be" is used in this sentence correctly

Tags: grammar

> WordPress 5.3 was released just a few hours ago. It will be the last
> major WordPress release of 2019.

I copied the above two sentences from one of the most popular blogs.

What I want to know is, is above sentence is grammatically correct or not?

I feel like it should be,

> WordPress 5.3 was released just a few hours ago. It **was**(or is) the last
> major WordPress release of 2019.

because it already happened.

---

I think it as following sentences.

> WordPress 5.3 **will be** released tomorrow. It **will be** the last
> major WordPress release of 2019.
>
> WordPress 5.3 **was** released just a few hours ago. It **was** the last
> major WordPress release of 2019.

Comment: Voting to close the Q as a NARQ.

Comment: It **is** grammatical and it is as it should be. Read it as "It **is going to be** the last major WordPress release of 2019."

Comment: @Kris Could you please explain to me why it said " It will be the last major WordPress release of 2019." even after it was released. I think something like this "WordPress 5.3 will be released tomorrow. It will be the last major WordPress release of 2019." correct with will be.

Comment: Because there's going to be no more releases in 2019. The two sentences are independent. The verbs refer to different things. Just think again.

Answer (score 2):

> WordPress 5.3 was released just a few hours ago. It is the last major
>   WordPress release of 2019.

This is grammatical, and would be used realistically near the end of 2019 (say within the last two weeks).

..................................

> WordPress 5.3 was released just a few hours ago. It was the last major
>   WordPress release of 2019.

This is not ungrammatical, but the past tense in the second sentence would not be used when commenting at a time still within 2019 (as 'just a few hours ago' almost certainly demands).

.................................

> WordPress 5.3 was released just a few hours ago. It will be the last
>   major WordPress release of 2019.

This is still not ungrammatical. Though it looks illogical, it is idiomatic (perfectly acceptable common phraseology) for

> WordPress 5.3 was released just a few hours ago. There will be no further
>   major WordPress release in 2019.